# Is there a better option than Union All for multiple selects from the same row?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Example Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Base](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Option1ID] [int] NULL,
[Option2ID] [int] NULL,
[Option3ID] [int] NULL,
[Option1Name] [varchar] NULL,
[Option2Name] [varchar] NULL,
[Option3Name] [varchar] NULL,
[Option1LName] [varchar] NULL,
[Option2LName] [varchar] NULL,
[Option3LName] [varchar] NULL,)
```

Is there a way to get results that show up like:

```
ID | OptionID | OptionName | OptionLName
```

I have tried to achieve this using UNION ALL but this means going over the same row 3 times in my example, in my real problem I have to do it 10 times. I cannot normalize the table due to legacy code. Is there a way to only go over the Base row once?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use `CROSS APPLY ... VALUES` to `UNPIVOT` multiple columns

```
SELECT ID,
       OptionID,
       OptionName,
       OptionLName
FROM   [dbo].[Base]
       CROSS APPLY (VALUES([Option1ID], [Option1Name], [Option1LName]),
                          ([Option2ID], [Option2Name], [Option2LName]),
                          ([Option3ID], [Option3Name], [Option3LName])) 
                     V( OptionID, OptionName, OptionLName)
```

The execution plan for this has one scan of `Base`. The plan is in fact the same as for the 2005 compatible rewrite that uses `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT ID,
       OptionID,
       OptionName,
       OptionLName
FROM   [dbo].[Base]
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT [Option1ID], [Option1Name], [Option1LName] UNION ALL
                    SELECT [Option2ID], [Option2Name], [Option2LName] UNION ALL
                    SELECT [Option3ID], [Option3Name], [Option3LName]) 
                     V( OptionID, OptionName, OptionLName)
```

But I presume the `UNION ALL` you were trying to avoid was the multiple scans of

```
SELECT ID,
       [Option1ID],
       [Option1Name],
       [Option1LName]
FROM   [dbo].[Base]
UNION ALL
SELECT ID,
       [Option2ID],
       [Option2Name],
       [Option2LName]
FROM   [dbo].[Base]
UNION ALL
SELECT ID,
       [Option3ID],
       [Option3Name],
       [Option3LName]
FROM   [dbo].[Base]
```